# The rotation of a rotating element

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Edit: this question is not about synchronocity.

I have a roulette type wheel which I plan to use with Node.js and figured out velocity and time so that everyone gets the same result by using CSS animations.

The problem being is that I don't want some people to know the result by others by overriding the animations - even though it takes away nothing I want everyone to see the result at the same time (something like setInterval will show different results on different machines or even the same machine with same inputs)

```
//jQuery
function spin() {
   spinning = true; //currently using clicks to trigger
   var r = Random(720000,1080000)/1000; //final angle to 3dp[![enter image description here][1]][1] (spins between 2 and 3 revolutions) - not going to just use a simple random number generator btw if you were getting worried.
   var t = (r*8)/360; //8s per revolution
   $(".wheel").css("transition", "transform " + t + "s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.34, 0.05, 0.95)").css("transform", "rotate(" + (r+a) + "deg)");
   a = (r+a)%360; //a is the current position
   setTimeout(correct, t*1000 + 250); //Set position to between 0 and 360
}

function correct() {
   spinning = false;
   $(".wheel").css("transition", "transform 0s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.34, 0.05, 0.95)").css("transform", "rotate(" + a + "deg)");
}
```

I am able to say which of the x number of slots is the result but it just isn't quite right.

• I would like to know which slot is under the arrow while it is spinning so the arrow can change colour to show clearly what the result is (in the event that the arrow is above a groove between slots):
[image: Arrows]
• I would ideally like to stop people from seeing the result immediately without waiting like everyone else, I would be fine with a final result variable being in JS - just not in the open for 1 line of CSS to overcome it.

I'm not sure how to do this transition in JavaScript where I pass in a result then carry out the animation while keeping track of rotation while changing acceleration and deceleration, and knowing what the arrow is pointing to while spinning.

Or should I just simulate on the server and feed out angles, even though that would be too much..?

---

## Edit: My current solution:

`angle=(-((time*(sqrt(finalAngle)/finalTime))-sqrt(finalAngle))^2)+finalAngle`
I will then use a timestamp to calculate the angle for the wheel, it allows for the easing I want, the synchonocity I want, the slight difficulty knowing what the result will be (as much as a client can do) and not require constant broadcasts using up bandwidth.

[**Interactive Graph**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vpb35cnyzz)

[image: Success!]

Comment: If you want everyone to see the same thing in realtime, look at socket.io it does exactly that

Comment: I'm using Node w/ Meteor to do that but that's not what my questions are about.

Comment: my point is, if you want to make sure everyone sees the data simultaneously, do the calculation on the server ;)

Comment: Would you suggest broadcasting an angle to everyone rather than allowing clients to do the animation? (could do CSS linear transitions to ease between like 20-50ms steps)

Comment: That could be a possibility, it's actually quite clever. You won't be able to stop people from overriding the animation if the client knows the result. Maybe you could broadcast something like '1slot' and then let the client handle the function to move the wheel one slot ?

Comment: or just broadcast a number, and have your function move the roulette by that number * predefined angle, that way if you want to make it happen faster/slower you have control over that

Comment: So far I think I will broadcast an angle with a liner CSS animation

Comment: @xShirase I have figured out that I can use `angle=(-((time*(sqrt(finalAngle)/finalTime))-sqrt(finalAngle))^2)+finalAngle` or something similar. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vpb35cnyzz